# jquery.min.js error 500 server internal DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm working in a web page with DataTable plugin, jQuery, AJAX, mySQL... I have a funny error and everything I red is not helping me.

I tested my page with Xampp and everything works fine. When I upload it to the server it give me an 500 internal server error and I where it is happening, but have no idea what is wrong.

I first have a login that works fine. Then I have this html:

```php
<?php 
  ob_start();
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
    session_start();

  if (!(isset($_SESSION['type'])) or ($_SESSION['type'] == "DATA ADMINISTRATOR")) 
    header("Location: ./index.php");

?>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Customer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Themes/style.css">

  <script src="./DataTables/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="./DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./DataTables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="./DataTables/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 1270px;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<header>
  <nav class="navigation-bar">
    <img class="logo" src='images/logo.png' />
  </nav>
  <nav class="navigation-menu" style=" width: 100%;height: 60px;background-color: #15937B;">
    <ul class="lista">
      <?php include "menu_others.php"; ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="container box">
    <h3 align="center" style="height:10px;">Customer</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <br />
      <div align="right">

      </div>
      <br />
      <table id="customer_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="20%">Name</th>
            <th width="20%">Contact No</th>
            <th width="20%">eMail</th>
            <th width="20%">Address</th>
            <th width="10%">Country</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#customer_data').DataTable({
      "processing": false,
      "serverSide": true,
      "order": [],
      "ajax": {
        url: "customer_fetch.php",
        type: "POST"
      },
      "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [],
        "orderable": false,
      }, ],
    });
  });
</script>
<?php
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

This is calling this php:

```php
<?php
    include('db.php');
    include('customer_function.php');
    $query = '';
    $output = array();
    
    $query .= "SELECT * FROM Customer, Country where country_id=country ";
    if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
    {
        $query .= 'AND ( NAME LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR address LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" )';
    }
    if(isset($_POST["order"]))
    {
        if ($_POST['order']['0']['column'] == 0)
            $query .= 'ORDER BY name ' .$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        if ($_POST['order']['0']['column'] == 1)
            $query .= 'ORDER BY contact_no ' .$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        if ($_POST['order']['0']['column'] == 2)
            $query .= 'ORDER BY email ' .$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        if ($_POST['order']['0']['column'] == 3)
            $query .= 'ORDER BY address ' .$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        if ($_POST['order']['0']['column'] == 4)
            $query .= 'ORDER BY country ' .$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
    }
    else
    {
        $query .= 'ORDER BY customer_ID DESC ';
    }
    if($_POST["length"] != -1)
    {
        $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }
    error_log($query);
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    error_log("prepared");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $data = array();
    $filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array[] = $row[1];
        $sub_array[] = $row[2];
        $sub_array[] = $row[3];
        $sub_array[] = $row[4];
        $sub_array[] = $row[7];
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row[0].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row[0].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
        $data[] = $sub_array;
    }
    
    $output = array(
        "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
        "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
        "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
        "data"              =>  $data
    );
    
    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

As you can see, I have an `error_log` to show me the query, this one is working fine, after that I have an `error_log` after the prepare statement, this is not working, so it looks like the error is when I do the prepare statement, I have not idea why.

Comment: Why are you using prepared statements without using placeholders? You're missing the whole point of prepared statements

Comment: you are rigth, that's wrong!!, thanks. Anywhay, it was not the problem, I finded out yesterday, after I wrote the question, that I wrote db.php instead of Db.php so it wasn' find the file. I don`t know how I can dismiss or close this question